# How to move post_content to wp_postmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I Created a small plugin to move post_content to wp_postmeta, but seem to have run into a wall.

see code below, it does not move the content at all, what am 'I doing wrong?

the code below should create a `meta_key=> product_content` and then the `meta_value=> post_content`.

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
    global $wpdb;
/*This is original get*/    
//$woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `post_content` , `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`=\'product\' AND `post_content`!=\'\'");
 $woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  `post_content` , `ID` FROM ". $wpdb->prefix . "posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND `post_content`!=''");

        foreach ($woo_products as $woo_product) {
            if ( ! add_post_meta( $woo_product->ID, 'product_content', $woo_product->post_content, true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta ( $woo_product->ID, 'product_content', $woo_product->post_content );
}
        }

   header("Location: https://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=product-manage");
    die();
?>
```

Comment: Instead of running `add_post_meta` and `update_post_meta`, just run your loop with some `echo` statements to see what it is doing. Also, to be clear, you are copying, not moving.

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes, I will be copying it, as I think it will be better to copy it, my second script deletes everything from post, but keeps the postmeta, so when I import from external source with ID the primary key it will still keep the post_content data

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I did the Echo and it is working as expected with the Product ID and post_content. Do you thing it would be better to move it than copying? The reason I ask is that The source only has the SKU, Product Name and ID, no Description/post_content So I do not want to lose the post_content on website when I import the SKU,product Name and ID. as I use Delete from wp_post where type='product'

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE CORRECT CODE, I JUST HAD TO DISABLE THE WP_CACHED PLUGIN THEN IT WORKED

```
<?php
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
    global $wpdb;
/*This is original get*/    
//$woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `post_content` , `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`=\'product\' AND `post_content`!=\'\'");
 $woo_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  `post_content` , `ID` FROM ". $wpdb->prefix . "posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND `post_content`!=''");

        foreach ($woo_products as $woo_product) {
            if ( ! add_post_meta( $woo_product->ID, 'product_content', $woo_product->post_content, true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta ( $woo_product->ID, 'product_content', $woo_product->post_content );
}
        }

   header("Location: https://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=product-manage");
    die();
?>
```